# SQL Query Add to total sum if.. else dont add

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How Do I achieve this result ? What I need is calculate total cost of a Product when a product is made up of components. New for me, I should add a 100$ to total cost if customer chooses for a service called Delivery.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
Select Sum(Component.Cost*ProductComponent.Quantity) as TotCost from ProductComponent Left Join Component on ProductComponent.ComponentId = Component.ComponentId
```

I Guess this will get me total cost of a product.

Now There is another table Service which has a many to many relationship with Order. Order has a many to many relationship with Service. What I need is I need to add another 100$ in total cost if there is 'deliverly' used in service.

I have attached an ER diagram of my database structure. I hope my question is clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you'd have to put a case statement in there to add the $100 if there is a record in the Service table for a given order.  The below query should get you most of the way there, but looking at the cardinality of your relationships you may need to group the results or use subqueries to chop it down to one row.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sa.ServiceID IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(Component.Cost*ProductComponent.Quantity) +    100
    ELSE SUM(Component.Cost*ProductComponent.Quantity) END AS TotCost 
FROM ProductComponent pc
LEFT JOIN Component on ProductComponent.ComponentId = Component.ComponentId 
JOIN OrderLine o ON o.ProductID = pc.ProductID
JOIN StaffAssignment sa ON sa.SaleID = o.SaleID
```

It looks like multiple StaffAssignments could give Service for one order so that's where you might want to use a subquery like `SELECT Top 1 ServiceID FROM StaffAssignment WHERE SaleID = o.SaleID AND ServiceID IS NOT NULL`

I don't have time to test this at the moment but hopefully it gives you some ideas to get this solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the service as another product and add it to the ones already there with a `UNION`

```
SELECT TotCost = SUM(LineCost)
FROM   (SELECT c.Cost * pc.Quantity as LineCost 
        FROM   OrderLine ol
               INNER JOIN ProductComponent p ON ol.ProductID = pc.ProductID
               LEFT  JOIN Component c on pc.ComponentId = c.ComponentId
        Where  ol.SaleID = @ID
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT 100
        FROM   StaffAssignment sa
               INNER JOIN Service s ON sa.ServiceID = s.ServiceID
        Where  Name = 'Delivery'
          And  sa.SaleID = @ID) a
```

Adding a field to the Services table would be useful, if the services have a flat values, to avoid to have magic constants in your code/queries